# Reading Java serialized object that has been split across two files?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm writing an Android application. One problem is your app cannot contain a file whose uncompressed size is bigger than about 1Mb. I have a serialized object that I want to load that totals about 2Mb. My plan was to split this file into two smaller files, then load the object by combining both files at runtime.

However, I cannot work out how to use e.g. InputStream and ObjectInputStream to specify that I want to read the data from two input streams. How can I do this?

For example, say my object was split between file O1 and O2. How can I say "Load the object by reading the data from O1 then from O2"?

Comment: In Java you could simply use `java.io.SequenceInputStream`. No idea about Android. Another solution might be to compress the stream again, but hide that from the platform. (You might want to change your tags, btw.)

Comment: @Tom: It looks like the Android SDK does contain an implementation of `java.io.SequenceInputStream` (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html). Why not post an answer so you get some reputation for it?

Comment: @Tom: I posted an answer with an example. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: @William I've already upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

As [Tom Hawtin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725/tom-hawtin-tackline) pointed out in the comments, you should be able to use Java's built-in [`SequenceInputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html) class to deserialize an object that is split across multiple files. This approach also allows you to deserialize an object split across any number of files, because `SequenceInputStream`'s constructor accepts two `InputStream` objects, one of which could be another `SequenceInputStream`.

I created a small example that should work on Android, although I have only tested it on a desktop Java installation. The example works on the assumption that you have serialized an object of type `Foo` and split the serialized version between two files names `myobj.part1` and `myobj.part2`.

The example is pretty self explanatory, but if you have any questions, please let me know.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;

...

ObjectInputStream in = null;

try {
    in = new ObjectInputStream(
        new SequenceInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("myobj.part1"),
                new FileInputStream("myobj.part2")));

    Foo foo = (Foo) in.readObject();

    // Do something with the deserialized object...
    foo.doSomething();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        try { 
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectInputStream` just takes the `InputStream` in its constructor, so clearly the task is implementing an `InputStream` concrete subclass that reads two files in sequence (rather than just one as `FileInputStream` does).  Basically your concrete subclass must implement [`read(byte[])`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) by delegating to the first, then (when that's exhausted) the second one of two `FileInputStream`s it holds as attributes (pass them into your concrete subclass's constructor).

Comment: I've considered doing it this way, but I would have thought this functionality would be hidden somewhere. I'd rather not write a new class if I can help it.

Comment: If you have `SequenceInputStream` in your Android SDK (sorry, don't have one to check), that's the predefined implementation that you're looking for, as Tom's comment and William's answer also indicate.